# W1035: Return value of function 'Take' might be undefined

Tags: delphi, exception, try-catch

I have a function to pop element from a dictionary, if anything goes wrong, an exception should be thrown. The code looks quite okay.

```
type 
  ENoSuchElementException = class(Exception);
var
  FResults: TDictionary<Cardinal, TObject> = TDictionary<Cardinal, TObject>.Create;
  FLock: TCriticalSection = TCriticalSection.Create;

/// <exceptions cref="ENoSuchElementException">Element does not exist</exceptions>
function Take(Id: Cardinal): TObject;
begin    
  FLock.Acquire;
  try
    try
      Result := FResults[Id]; // here may throw exception
      FResults.Remove(Id);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        raise ENoSuchElementException.Create(E.ToString);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FLock.Release;
  end;
end;
```

But the Delphi XE4 compiler complains about `W1035: Return value of function 'Take' might be undefined`.

I am suddenly so confused. If an exception is thrown, why the code still expect a return value? Does it mean that `try...finally` will eat the exception? Can someone point out the problem of my code?

**RESOLVED:** As David mentioned, the `try...except` should be moved to outer. Thanks!

Comment: Sigh. Couldn't we have had an SSCCE? Now each of us have to spend time making one.

Comment: @David, I've updated the code example, it should be more compact now.

Comment: An SSCCE is really what is needed

Comment: I'm curious why you want to covert a regular exception into a silent one - if you don't want the usual error box, you can handle that globally.

Comment: @chris look at edit history. The original code had logging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - thanks, I see now. Still a bit odd why you wouldn't do this globally... but a lot less odd than catching only to re-raise as EAbort.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston Yes, the original code looks odd to me. Catching exceptions as soon as they are thrown, logging, and then re-throwing. Not good.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 You really should use `ExtractPair` rather than the code in the question. The code in the question performs two lookups. `ExtractPair` can do it in one,

Comment: @DavidHeffernan (1) Originally I want to catch all kinds of exception but throw only one acceptable exception. You can imagine by handling JSON-RPC, all kinds of error will be returned as an EInternalServerError. The error description will hint more details. (2) I have updated the code example above already. Does `ExtractPair` mean to remove the element from a dictionary as well?

Comment: Yes. The convention in Emba containers is that anything named Extract removes the item from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a false positive reported by the 32 bit compiler. The 64 bit compiler does not report a warning for your code. And the 64 bit compiler is correct. Perhaps the 32 bit compiler sees that you are catching the exception and does not go on to detect that you always subsequently raise another exception.

One way to work around the 32 bit compiler's mis-diagnosis is to make the try/except be the outer-most block. Consider the following SSCCE:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure Foo;
begin
end;

function Take1(const Id: Integer): Integer;
begin
  try
    try
      Foo;
      Result := 42;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        raise Exception.Create(E.ToString);
      end;
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;

function Take2(const Id: Integer): Integer;
begin
  try
    try
      Foo;
      Result := 42;
    finally
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(E.ToString);
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
end.
```

The compiler's output is:

```
[dcc32 Warning] W1035 Return value of function 'Take1' might be undefined
```

So, `Take1` is my simplified version of your code. The 32 bit compiler warns for that. And `Take2` swaps the order of the `except` and `finally`. And the compiler does not warn.

Perhaps this workaround is not the one for you, but you will have to come up with something of this nature.

The bottom line is that your analysis is correct, and the compiler is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have a 64 bit compiler, however the build configuration is 32 bit. I have a self rewritten VCL library, which can never be installed in 64 bit mode. I can only compile it in 64 bit mode. This is the reason why I build my code with a 32 bit compiler.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you compiler for 64 bit. I did not write that.

Comment: Oh yes. Now I see the problem in my code. I was somehow connected my brain with Java/D etc, as these languages have a different `try...catch...finally` handling.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is fine. The compiler is at fault. Anyway, I think having the exception handler outmost is probably cleaner code so that's probably a nice expedient solution.

Comment: I will remember the usage and just wondered, after so many years, Delphi still does not merge `try/finally` and `try/except` as one `try/except/finally`. Code `try try` looks really ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

David Heffernan's given you the most direct answer, however an alternative is to avoid the `try`/`except` block completely and use the `TryGetValue` method of `TDictionary`. Going a bit further, you could if you wanted to also get rid of the separate locking object:

```
var FResults: TDictionary<Cardinal, TResult>;

function Take(Id: Cardinal): TResult;
begin    
  TMonitor.Enter(FResults);
  try
    if FResults.TryGetValue(Id, Result) then
      FResults.Remove(Id)
    else
      Abort;
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(FResults);
  end;
end;
```

`TMonitor` historically had significant bugs, but it will be OK in XE4.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler recognise `Abort`? In other words, do you need to write `Result := nil` after `Abort` given that `Abort` raises.

Comment: Yes, your approach works as well. But I want to take the advantage of exceptions. The benefit is that where I call the method, I do not have to check whether the value is null. For me, it will be perfectly clear, a method will return a not null value or an exception.

Comment: I give you an example: to get an element from a list, I will usually have two methods: `getElement(Condition)` and `requireElement(Condition)`. `get` means, it might return null, but `require` means it will throw an exception if nothing can be returned. I have a project https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/dutil/, you can checkout the two validation classes, and you will understand .

Comment: Do you think `try...except` is evil? Although the Delphi IDE does not prompt on unhanded exceptions very well, but I believe using exception is a more modern programming style.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I made the original post (no IDE open) without it, then thought 'whoops' and made the edit... only after which I actually tried, and indeed, no hint without it. However, the `Abort` doesn't prevent the hint - passing the value as a var or out param to another method does (XE3 - I'm in the middle of installing a later version so can't try anything else at the moment).

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 (1) you aren't 'taking advantage of exceptions' by blindly handling every one in order to re-raise a generalised, silent one instead; (2) re-raising a silent exception is clearly not the same as returning nil; (3) it's a normal Delphi idiom to provide TryXXX and XXX alternatives when invalid input is a less than truly 'exceptional' occurrence (cf. StrToInt/TryStrToInt); (4) this only helps 'avoid' (mis)using exceptions as a general signalling mechanism; (5) TBH, your posted lines reminded me of Java code that tries to avoid the annoyances of Java's checked exception system...

Comment: @ChrisRolliston Normally I put possible exception in method comment, which will be hinted in Delphi IDE. Yes, I know my approach is not normal Delphi idiom. It is more borrowed from a language D library, called Tango. Anyway, thanks for letting me be clear about `try/except`.